# How to update UITableViewController in a UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I present my popover like this:

```
UITableViewController *tbv = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.listTableViewController = tbv;
tbv.tableView.delegate = self;
tbv.tableView.dataSource = self;

[self setupPopoverControllerForViewController:tbv];

[self.popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.popoverButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
[tbv release];
```

When something gets deleted in the tableView, I want to update it.  I've tried both of these:

```
    [self.listTableViewController.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.indexPathToDelete] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.listTableViewController.tableView reloadData];
```

but neither work.  If I close the popover, then reopen it.  My table is then updated.  It just doesn't update it while it's open like I want.  Thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried calling a "setNeedsDisplay" on the popover view?

Comment: Are you sure the code where you call `[self.listTableViewController.tableView reloadData]` is actually being called?

Comment: @trumpetlicks Yes I just tried that.  It does not seem to refresh the table.  I did it with `[self.popover.contentViewController.view setNeedsDisplay];`

Comment: Are you deleting the actual data from the dataSource?  If the table is showing information from an array, you would have to delete the information at the index corresponding to the row i.e [array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

Comment: Make sure that `self.listTableViewController.tableView reloadData];` executes after the data is removed from the dataSource.  If you are sure that it is, set a breakpoint on the deleting line. `po` the datasource before and after the delete to make sure that the deleted data is actually getting removed